# Can't insert list data to sql server table using c#

Tags: c#, sql-server, list, sql-insert

I have a method in c# that accepts a list and its purpose is  to insert it into a SQL Server table, but it doesn't insert at all, can you please help me here. any insights is very much appreciated.

Here is my code

```
public void insertToDB(List<PlantillaData> plantillaDataList)
{
   IsqlConnect db = new IsqlConnect();
   string conQuery = db.connectionQuery;
   SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conQuery);

   try
   {
      con.Open();

      foreach (PlantillaData plantillaData in plantillaDataList)
      {
         SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO dbo.t_employee(Telephone_Number_1," +
                    "Employee_Number,Employee_LastName,Employee_FirstName,Employee_MiddleName," +
                    "Cluster,Division,Department,Unit,Supervisor,Email,EWB_Rank,Position," +
                    "Location,Employee_Category)VALUES(@telNum1,@empNum,@empLastName,@empFirstName," +
                    "@empMiddleName,@cluster,@division,@unit,@supervisor,@email,@rank," +
                    "@position,@location,@emp_cat) ", con);

         cmd.Parameters.Add("@telNum1", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = plantillaData.telOneVal;
         cmd.Parameters.Add("@empNum", SqlDbType.Int).Value = plantillaData.empNumVal;
         cmd.Parameters.Add("@empLastName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = plantillaData.lName;
         cmd.Parameters.Add("@empFirstName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = plantillaData.fName;
         cmd.Parameters.Add("@empMiddleName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = plantillaData.mName;
         cmd.Parameters.Add("@cluster", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = plantillaData.clusterVal;
         cmd.Parameters.Add("@division", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = plantillaData.divVal;
         cmd.Parameters.Add("@unit", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = plantillaData.unitVal;
         cmd.Parameters.Add("@supervisor", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = plantillaData.supervisorVal;
         cmd.Parameters.Add("@email", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = plantillaData.emailVal;
         cmd.Parameters.Add("@rank", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = plantillaData.rankVal;
         cmd.Parameters.Add("@position", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = plantillaData.posVal;
         cmd.Parameters.Add("@location", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = plantillaData.locVal;
         cmd.Parameters.Add("@emp_cat", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = 1;

         try
         {
             con.Open();
             cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
         }
         catch
         {
         }
         finally
         {
             con.Close();
         }
      }
   }
   catch (Exception e)
   {
      throw new Exception("SQL Error:" + e.Message.ToString());
   }
   finally
   {
      con.Close();
   }
}
```

Comment: See if your inner `try-catch` contains some error

Comment: `catch {}` - **never** do that again

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a department value for the VALUES field in the insert query right before the Unit. If you had trapped and displayed the error you would have got the violation

Comment: Thanks @lloydom but i have already added that item and still cannot load it to database.

Comment: have you also added the department parameter too in the cmd.parameter section?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you open the connection twice?
Are you sure you have Items in your List?
Do you get any Exceptions?

The inner catch will prevent calling the outer catch-block!

Comment: Sorry for that, i have changed that too and still cannot load it.

Comment: i dont get any exceptions on this, i have modified my code and was able to load at least 12 items only, but my count on my list is 3900+